# MonoRail - how to call server-side method from jQuery

Tags: castle-monorail

I'm trying to call a server-side action in a controller from jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost:88/admin/business/11/GetChildBusinessTypes',
            data: { parentId: $('#business_parentbusinesstype_id').val() },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: fillChildBusinessTypes,
            error: ajaxError
        });
```

Here is the controller action:

```
public string GetChildBusinessTypes(int parentId)
        {
            //get child business types.
            var businessTypes = BusinessTypeRepository.GetChildBusinessTypes(parentId);
            //convert to JSON.
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize(businessTypes);
        }
```

It's giving me this error:

**MonoRail could not resolve a view engine instance for the template 'admin\business\GetChildBusinessTypes' There are two possible reasons: either the template does not exist, or the view engine that handles an specific file extension has not been configured correctly web.config (section monorail, node viewEngines).**

It's clear it's trying to get the action as if it were a view and erroring out. I tried sending it as a POST instead of a GET but receive the same rror. What do I need to do to get this to work?

Thanks!
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer for others who are looking to call controller actions from jQuery and return JSON...

Controller Method:

```
[return: JSONReturnBinder(Properties = "Id,Name")]
        public BusinessType[] GetChildBusinessTypes(int parentId)
        {
            var businessTypes = BusinessTypeRepository.GetChildBusinessTypes(parentId);
            return businessTypes;
        }
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#business_parentbusinesstype_id').change(function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "$UrlHelper.For("%{action='$business.site.id/GetChildBusinessTypes'}")",
                data: { parentId: $('#business_parentbusinesstype_id').val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                success: fillChildBusinessTypes,
                error: ajaxError
            });
        });
    });

    function fillChildBusinessTypes(json) {
        //get business types.
        var businessTypes = eval(json);
        //bind business types to dropdown.
        $("#business_businesstype_id").get(0).options.length = 0;
        $("#business_businesstype_id").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select a Business Type", "0");
        jQuery.each(businessTypes, function(index, item) {
            $('#business_businesstype_id').get(0).options[$("#business_businesstype_id").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Name, item.Id);
        });
        //show child dropdown.
        Show($('#spnChildBusinessTypes'));
    }
```